# Improve backticks help text

Tags: feature-request, help-text

I found the [Markdown help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) confusing:

> Use backticks to create an inline  `span:`
>
> Press the `<Tab>` key, then type a `$`.

It's confusing because the second line itself is formatted using inline code span.  It would be clearer to also display the rendered line (with "<Tab>" and "$" as code, and no backticks).

Comment: And indeed, [some *are* typing `<Tab>`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3945c79c-9901-44de-8734-b4087b768ffa/view-source) ([screen capture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vzhc3.png)) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the whole of that page does *not* show the output of any markdown, only the markup.

Perhaps it could be a little more explicit that this is the case, but it is clear well before you've read the whole thing.