# Trouble formatting pasted text

Tags: support, code-formatting

When I paste a long block of text in the question editor on SO (and probably other stack exchange sites), it randomly makes the text wrap-around to a new line after a couple of words, but it's a strange new line. When I put the cursor just in front of the new line and press backspace once, the word on the previous line sticks in front of the second line...

Images explaining:

[image: image 1]
<sub>(source: [mediafire.com](http://www.mediafire.com/conv/06697288b4ecd26c5f4112fe0ab43fb082a1e071d52efc6090d5892e4db563356g.jpg))</sub>

[image: image 2]
<sub>(source: [mediafire.com](http://www.mediafire.com/conv/a5a32d82d6add7b7671fb0619d1da83e841b4e2c96f2a0e21e2dc6213b03e6ba6g.jpg))</sub>

[image: image 3]
<sub>(source: [mediafire.com](http://www.mediafire.com/conv/65e39d68da8ab1df658845ed27c937c097b3e94c7c17120f208d3dcbd1a828f36g.jpg))</sub>

[image: image 4]
<sub>(source: [mediafire.com](http://www.mediafire.com/conv/8577dd661d8eab62dc5cbb3b2adcefb1325c7f85c32318e15b826a92867845246g.jpg))</sub>

This is especially annoying when trying to format code. I've only just found out about the ctrl+k shortcut, and I am disappointed that it isn't really shown to the user. Also the help says to use the tab key to indent, but this key swaps focus (in Firefox at least).

What does the editor do to long texts exactly? I can't be the only one confused with this...

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean. Could you post an example text or a screenshot?

Comment: @Dennis Sorry, I'll look into optimising the question with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Where does the help say to use the Tab *key*? (That would be wrong.) I assume it's saying that tabs are fine, like: when *pasting* code that was indented using tabs. Or [Improve backticks help text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51894/improve-backticks-help-text) needs your vote.

Comment: Though I don't understand the problem you're describing, it might be related to having non-breaking spaces (U+00A0) in your paste; see [Why do code blocks sometimes not “show” properly?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125658/why-do-code-blocks-sometimes-not-show-properly) and [Indenting markdown with non-regular unicode spaces does not create a correct code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125587/indenting-markdown-with-non-regular-unicode-spaces-does-not-create-a-correct-cod).

Comment: @Dennis I updated my question to include images.

Comment: I think @Arjan is right: You probably have some funky whitespace characters in your paste. Could you create an answer here or in the [sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox), so we can check?

Comment: If you want to format code, then highlight it and click the image on the toolbar that looks like `{}`.  If you hover over that, you will notice the CTRL-K hint, and the note that `{}` is for code samples.  You could also click the `?` button, and follow the advanced help link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems fine to me: it's just that the HTML textarea does not have a horizontal scrollbar, and is not breaking on dots-without-whitespace. Just like here<sup>†</sup>, I don't think that `'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission` would fit on that first line. Try typing a space before `ReflectionPermission` to see what I mean, like `'System.Security.Permissions. ReflectionPermission`.

It is, technically, still one line, that is wrapped in the editor. When formatted as code, then in the preview and the final result you will see one line, and a scrollbar to make the content fit.

<sup>†</sup> [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxXWX.png) of regular website.

Comment: but code is supposed to stay on one line for an indefinite length. I just **cannot** get the first line of the stack trace on the same line without using ctrl+k...

Comment: (Yep, just added that to my answer, Mario.)

Comment: Well I'm sorry to tell you that it wasn't like that in the preview, nor in the final version. Whatever I tried doing without using ctrl+k...

Comment: Well, if you add four spaces before `[SecurityException` then that line is surely formatted code, and hence show the horizontal scrollbar to make the wrapped line fit. But: that is not visible in the editor indeed. That said: posting long stack traces is rarely useful.

Comment: In my answer I got it working now... strange... I swear it didn't work in the question. Or I was doing something wrong...

Comment: Still, Mario, your screenshots (nice!) simply show me that you're adding more whitespace between `of type` and the long `'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission` (you could have typed any other text after `of type` to see the same effect). And then in the 4th step remove *all* whitespace, which gives you an even longer `type'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission` that just doesn't fit on that first line. I see you wrote you only removed *the last* added space, but I think you're mistaken there. (Were all spaces selected when you pressed the delete button?)

Comment: Yes I'm sure :) I'll remember what I did in my answer to make it work for the future. Thanks for taking the time to explain!

Comment: Final note, you can open the editor and then paste the following into the location bar of your browser to once get horizontal scrollbars: `javascript:$("textarea").css("white-space", "nowrap");` (If you're getting security errors, then try adding some more semi-colons to fool the browser. Your browser might also remove the word `javascript:` to be more secure. But that is really needed.)

Comment: That would be handy if absolutely necessary :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked me to paste it here:

[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +31
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
   System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.PerformSecurityCheck(Type owner, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean skipVisibility) +166
   System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor(String name, Type returnType, Type[] parameterTypes, Type owner, Boolean skipVisibility) +40
   NHibernate.Bytecode.Lightweight.ReflectionOptimizer.CreateDynamicMethod(Type returnType, Type[] argumentTypes) in ReflectionOptimizer.cs:104

Strange thing is that I get this **every time** with no matter what I pasted...

Comment: Is it not in a code block on purpose? [Looks fine to me](http://i.imgur.com/9Jya7.png) when its in a code block (CTRL+K)...

Comment: @Lix I know it works with ctrl+k. I got no more issues now strangely, when trying to format in code, but still the line breaks that are automatically added behave kind of strange...

Comment: These are not really automatically added line breaks, Mario. It's [word wrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_wrap). The edit text area cannot have horizontal scrollbars as then regular text would become hard to read. (It's nice to have long paragraphs wrapped over multiple lines.)